# Getting deadlocks very frequently in Mysql insert query

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

```
=2023-09-15 15:16:35 0x1530b7bc17002023-09-15 15:16:35 0x1530b7bc1700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 55060584750, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 10640581, OS thread handle 23400148567808, query id 455015502 10.1.13.206 admin update
INSERT IGNORE INTO `product_config` (`merchant_id`,`config_path`,`value`) VALUES ('58541','product_access_token','456670849.oo0Dm0YB-oV73AqMvcEf6Ysm3'),('58541','product_refresh_token','456670849.jxeCmCd8Sgvit7QlZLBTmqBjLO4dW-XsYv'),('58541','product_access_token_secret','456670849.jxeCmCd8SgvxSJS4-QlZLBTmqBjLO4dW-XsYv'),('58541','token_expire_time',1694790995) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`= VALUES(`value`)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3075 page no 6615 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `marketplace_integration`.`product_config` trx id 55060584750 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=8; bufptr=0x153946e98070; hex= 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 55060584749, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 10640966, OS thread handle 23400144643840, query id 455015500 10.1.10.11 admin update
INSERT IGNORE INTO `product_config` (`merchant_id`,`config_path`,`value`) VALUES ('112043','product_access_token','290096243.BFg3suqIMxIpb5u18AnXG41piKXKxJ7ZzHSXMBflaN8iRqER4-W7WUf-jr'),('112043','product_refresh_token','290096243.LPs2VNdIuI6xniq71DsMG5xXFXPnv8Y'),('112043','product_access_token_secret','290096243.LPs2VNdIuxXFXPnv8Y'),('112043','token_expire_time',1694790995) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`= VALUES(`value`)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3075 page no 6615 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `marketplace_integration`.`product_config` trx id 55060584749 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=8; bufptr=0x153946e98070; hex= 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3075 page no 6615 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `marketplace_integration`.`product_config` trx id 55060584749 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=8; bufptr=0x153946e98070; hex= 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

MySQL version 5.7

Table structure-

```
CREATE TABLE `product_config` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `merchant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `config_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` text,
  `updated_at_new` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at_new` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `post_product_config_idx` (`merchant_id`,`config_path`),
  KEY `merchant_id` (`merchant_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_config_merchant_id` FOREIGN KEY (`merchant_id`) REFERENCES `product_shop_details` (`merchant_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1168788710 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I am getting four deadlocks in an hour after the reboot of the MySQL server.

Comment: Deadlocks are related to how your application accesses the database. Without knowing the application, it is not possible to advise how to resolve the root cause of deadlocks.

Comment: is there something wrong with the query or the table structure and indexing that are causing deadlocks? because 4 days ago server was rebooted and after that deadlock on this query start occurring before that on this query I have never received deadlocks

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa kindly suggest the points i need to check in my database i am getting deadlocks very frequently after server restart before that i haven't received deadlock on the query mentioned in the innodb report.  my innodb_lock_wait_timeout is 120 secs

Comment: Unfortunately I can only advise on technical questions, not to do your work for you. Please contact the application vendor support why their software is causing deadlocks.

Comment: Did you delete some merchants with lots of rows?  (`ON DELETE CASCADE`)

Answer (score 0):

- `KEY` merchant_id `(`merchant_id`),` can be dropped since the `UNIQUE` can handle any needs for that index.  (This is likely to decrease the I/O.)
- Presumably `merchant_id` and `config_path` could actually be `NOT NULL`?  (This won't fix anything, but it is necessary for my next suggestion.)
- It seems that `id` could be removed and the `UNIQUE` be promoted to `PRIMARY KEY`.  This would, for example, keep the two `INSERTs` listed away from each other.  Currently they are probably trying to insert onto the end of the table (for new `id` values) while reaching back into the table to check for dups on the `UNIQUE` key.  (Cutting back on I/O may help avoid deadlocks.)
- If there were other queries running, they may have impacted the deadlock without showing up in the `STATUS`.  Were other processes running?
- Live with deadlocks -- when you get one , rerun the query; it will almost always run quietly on the second try.  Are you still getting 4 deadlocks per hour?  Was there a flurry of pent up Inserts after the reboot?  How many `INSERTs` per hour now?
- Consider getting rid of the `ON CASCADE DELETE`, perhaps such was running through lots and lots of rows.  Note that my PK recommendation would cluster all the rows for a given `merchant_id` together, thereby minimizing I/O.
- What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  How big (in GB) is `product_config`?  (These may lead to another recommendation.)